How to express merging two texts with common phrases?
We have two texts in a way that each has some unique phrases and some duplicate phrases within it. I want to ask someone to merge the two texts, keep the unique phrases of both ones and merge the duplicate ones. How do I best explain this in a short sentence?

Does the resulting text have to be grammatical?  Putting two phrases side-by-side could easily result in borderline gibberish (e.g. "in a blue dress wearing a blue dress").   In textual editing what normally happens is that one text is considered the best and variants are shown in footnotes. Lacunae can be filled from variant texts. But texts are not simply "merged".

I'm not actually trying to find out the best practice on merging two texts, I'm looking for the correct word, imagine I have 2 paragraphs describing a car, each describing it from a specific aspect, if I write a new text using information from both of the paragraphs, what is it called?

Please merge the two texts and make it concise.

There's no name for that, which is what "what is it called?" is asking for. You can describe it:  Write a new article using these two as a basis.  I don't mean to be nitpicking but "using information", the phrase you use in your comment, is far different from "keep the unique phrases and merge the duplicate ones".  Is a human being going to do this, or an algorithm? Are you giving this instruction to AI or to a person?

That there's actually no word or expression to describe it answered my question @TimR thank you

You might say, "edit them together", which implies that it's not an automatic function and there's some degree of human intervention (i.e., editing) required to avoid the gibberish that @TimR was referring to.
